# Querying Multiple Google Analytics Raw tables in Bigquery by data range throwing error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Trying to get the list of fullVisitorID of people in last three days.

```
SELECT   fullVisitorID
FROM   (TABLE_DATE_RANGE(74638019.ga_sessions, 
                    TIMESTAMP('2014-08-19'), 
                    TIMESTAMP('2014-08-21')))
```

I'm getting the following error:

Error: Encountered "" at line 2, column 26. Was expecting one of:

I used exactly as mentioned in the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#tablewildcardfunctions

PS: Posting for the first time. Couldn't get the formating well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the table name with '[]':

```
SELECT   fullVisitorID
FROM   (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([74638019.ga_sessions], 
                    TIMESTAMP('2014-08-19'), 
                    TIMESTAMP('2014-08-21')))
```